# Problem in $NP \cap coNP$ and in P implies $NP=P$?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, np

Suppose that we have a problem in $NP \cap coNP$, if we find an algorithm that solves the problem in P, does this mean that $NP=P$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. $P$ is a subset op both $NP$ and $coNP$ so any problem in $P$ is in $NP\cap coNP$. To show that $NP=P$ you need to show that all problems in $NP$ have a polynomial time solution.

If you would show that a $NP$-complete problem is in $NP\cap coNP$ however you would show $NP=P$.

Answer (score 1):

Not at all.

Take *any* problem in P. Then the problem is automatically in NP and in co-NP, and therefore in the intersection, so you would conclude that P = NP. Because of one problem in P. That's obviously not correct.